# How to calculate Corner radius?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i am going to design laptop sticker for inner side, so i am came up with how to calculate corner radius i hv marked below with picture that attached?
can any one give me solution
thank you
i am not good in English sry for mistakes 
thank you

[image]

Comment: I'd do like this: Draw a vertical line and an horizontal (or guide line) one corresponding to the border of the rectangle. Put a vertical one when you think the corner is starting to be be rounder, you should get an the intersection, you should get the rounding value (distance). You can draw a "regular" circle from that point to check that the rounded corner is "correct" and not custom made.

Comment: @Larme please post Answers such as that as an Answer

Comment: I wasn't sure about that answer, so I was giving hints/tip (so the user can see/test) before I can test it later, and add screenshot and more explanations on a "real answer".

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea to try to find the radius of such a rectangle (See images below)

1. Draw vertical and horizontal guides on all 4 sides
2. Pick up the Rounded Rectangle tool
3. Making sure Snap to Guide is turned on, draw from the top left corner to the bottom right corner, the edges should snap
4. The resulting rectangle may not have the right radius as mine does not, if the Properties is not displayed select it from the Windows menu
5. Make sure the color is set to white for easy visibility, border to none, and the lock at the center of four corners is clicked on
6. Each corner icon is a scrubby slider, click and drag any one of them to increase or decrease the radius of all corners until you do not see the underlying area
7. Now, read the radius number. In my example it turned out to be 52 pixels.

Here are some screen captures:

[image: With guides drawn]

[image: Rounded rectangle tool]

[image: With rounded corners]

[image: Properties]

[image: Radius adjusted to fit]

[image: Read the radius]